# What's the origin of the name "The Orville"?

Tags: names, the-orville

What's the origin of the name *U.S.S. Orville* (in and out of universe) in the upcoming Seth MacFarlane Star Trek comedy/spoof *The Orville*?

(Is it related to [Orville Wright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_brothers))?

Comment: I'm pledging to offer a bounty of +50 on the first **five** quality *Orville*-related questions.   You asked the questions, I'll add the bounties.   (Quality is up to me...)    Let's get this party started!

Comment: I'm going with Seth's a huge fan of popcorn.

Comment: @ThePopMachine You man want to write a meta post about your 'Topic Challenge'

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Per this [tweet](https://twitter.com/SethMacFarlane/status/864264403931344898) from series writer/director Seth MacFarlane, the ship is named after [Orville Wright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_brothers) of "Wright Brothers" fame

> **Q.** *Seth, why did you call it the Orville?*
>
> **Seth Macfarlane:** *I was reading [David McCullough's Wright brothers biography](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22609391-the-wright-brothers) while writing the pilot.  Seemed fitting.*

Comment: Not Capt. [Howard Thomas Orville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_Thomas_Orville) of the U. S. Navy?

Comment: @User14111 - Nor, disappointingly, is it named after Orville the Duck.

Comment: Could've sworn it was to honor the late [Orville Redenbacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orville_Redenbacher).

Comment: I guess "The Wilbur" didn't have the same ring to it.

Comment: Not Orville Redenbacher, either. So disappointing.

Answer (score 11):

Based on the presence of a model of the Wright brothers' airplane *[the Wright Flyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_Flyer)* on Mercer's desk in multiple episodes, I would say yes, it is named for Orville Wright

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Seth MacFarlane is an scientifically literate person.
There are 2 situations that came to mind.

1 - The d'Orville Euclid, dated 888, is the earliest "complete" manuscript of Euclid'sOffsite Link ElementsOffsite Link, and, according to the Bodleian Library exhibition catalogue, The Survival of Greek Literature, it is the oldest manuscript of a classical Greek author to bear a date.

2 - Orville Wright was the youngest of the Wright brothers, that made the first plane.

I think I'm not too far from the truth.